# tkinter labels going off the screen. anyway to detect this

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, label

I have some python code putting tkinter labels on the canvas in question using a loop. My question is if the array being looped on prints 12 labels, sometimes they fit on the screen, and sometimes they don't if the labels contain big text.

Is there a clever way to break this loop if the screen width has been exhausted

```
l_row_start_display=6 
for l in G_DATA_VIEW_LABELS_ARRAY: ## list of lists of labels
      l_cnt=0
      for lab in l:
         l_align='W'             
         lab.grid(row=l_row_start_display,
                column=l_cnt,sticky=l_align) 
         l_cnt+=1
      l_row_start_display+=1
```

or any other ideas

thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer to include 2 examples of how to get something close to what you are wanting. One uses `.grid()` and the other uses `.place()`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I have found a way to do this while still using `.grid()` to place the labels. We can use a frame in the man window and then get the size of the frame with `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()`. Using this information and getting the height and width of the frame after each label is made we can then decide when to end the while statement. This will give us a rough amount of accuracy when placing labels. the only problem is it will measure the current frame size and not the size of the widget so you may need to play around with the numbers to get it to where you want.

Here is the example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x300")

l = ["SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT"]
screen = root.winfo_width()
my_frame = Frame(root)
my_frame.pack(expand=True)

last_row = 0
last_column = 0
my_frame_x = my_frame.winfo_width()
my_frame_y = my_frame.winfo_height()
b = True
while b == True:
    for stuff in l:
        if my_frame_x > 450 or my_frame_y > 250:
            print ("Labels cannot be outside of window!")
            b = False
        else:
            lablabel = Label(my_frame) 
            lablabel.config(text = stuff)         
            lablabel.grid(row = last_row, column = last_column)
            last_row += 1
            last_column += 1
            my_frame.update()
            my_frame_x = my_frame.winfo_width()
            my_frame_y = my_frame.winfo_height()

root.mainloop()
```

You can also do this with the `.place()` layout manager. All you need to do is define the max pixel x and y you would like your labels to be created at.

For example I have a window that is set to 800x300 and I have configure the label generator to not create any more labels once the pixel limit has been reached. This is done by defining the pixel size of the label, adding that size to the next position and then check to make sure the new x and y numbers don't exceed your predefined sizes.

Take a look at this example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x300")
root.minsize(800, 300)


l = ["SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT", "SOME TEXT"]
last_x = 0
last_y = 0
b = True
while b:
    for stuff in l: 
        last_x+=100
        last_y+=30
        if last_x > 700 or last_y > 270:
            b = False
            print ("Labels cannot be outside of window!")

        else:
            lablabel = Label(root) 
            lablabel.config(text = stuff)         
            lablabel.place(x = last_x, y = last_y, width = 100) 

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The width is unknown due to the dynamic nature of the labels text. This is why I can not do it this way.

Comment: @Ab Bennett: I have done a lot of looking around and have been unable to find anything that could "detect"  anything outside of the visible window. The closest thing I was able to come up with is to measure the frame until the frame became bigger than a defined size.Because the frame will expand until it matches the size of the parent window you can use it in this way. But other than that I am not sure if you can do what you want.

Comment: @Ab Bennett: If you do manage to find an answer I would love to know :)

Answer (score 1):

I tinkered with Ron Norris' reply and came up with this. The function keeps adding characters to the string until it reaches it's max width. It uses the font assigned to the widget to calculate the width of the string in pixels before comparing it to the widget's width.

```
def clip_string(widget, string, offset=0, suffix=''):
    max_w = widget.winfo_width() # max width in pixels
    max_w += offset # adjust for offset
    max_w -= (widget['bd']*2) # substract the borderwidth
    font = tkFont.Font(widget, widget.cget("font")) # get widget's font
    new_string = ''
    for char in range(0,len(string)): # add characters until string is at max
        new_string += string[char] # add character
        str_pixels = font.measure(new_string + suffix, widget)
        if str_pixels > (max_w):
            string = new_string + suffix
            break
    return string
```

Here it is in a quick demo. Adjust the width of the 'Entry' widget and the string will clip accordingly.

Note that we're importing tkinter.font

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont

def clip_string(widget, string, offset=0, suffix=''):
    max_w = widget.winfo_width() # Gax width in pixels
    max_w += offset # Adjust for offset
    max_w -= (widget['bd']*2) # Substract the borderwidth
    font = tkFont.Font(widget, widget.cget("font")) # Get widget's font
    new_string = ''
    for char in range(0,len(string)): # add chars until string is at max
        new_string += string[char] # add character
        str_pixels = font.measure(new_string + suffix, widget) # Measure
        if str_pixels > max_w:
            string = new_string + suffix
            break
    return string

root = Tk()
root.geometry('375x90')

# Create 'Entry' widget
display_txt = StringVar()
entry_widget = Entry(root,
                    textvariable = display_txt,
                    bd = 7 # borderwidth is taken into account
                    )
entry_widget.place(x=30,y=30, width=300, height=35) # try changing the width
entry_widget.update_idletasks() # needs to update to get real size

string = "this is my really long string so let's see where it gets cut off"
clipped_string = clip_string(
                            widget = entry_widget, # Widget to measure
                            string = string, # Our long string
                            offset = -12, # Offset in pixels
                            suffix = '..' # Chars we want to add
                             )
display_txt.set(clipped_string) # set the new string

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Measuring the font is the key.

```
import tkinter.font
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# Get a font object
font_obj = tkinter.font.Font()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.grid()
string_list = []
string_list.append('the text that is too wide for the canvas and I need to know that it is')
string_list.append('this text will fit')

# Iterate through the strings, getting the number of pixels it takes.
# Note that this can be configured larger or smaller based on need.
can_width = int(canvas['width'])
i = 0
for s in string_list:
    str_pixels = font_obj.measure(s, canvas)
    # Compare the width of the canvas to the number of str_pixels
    if str_pixels <= can_width:
        y = (i + 1) * 20
        canvas.create_text(10,y,anchor='nw',text=s,font='TkDefault')
        i += 1
    else:
        # Print a warning, ignore, whatever when the string is too long.
        print("'" + s + "'", "is too long to display in canvas")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this code gives an error. `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name "TkDefault"` please provide functioning code.